# knockout validation on delay

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js. I need to have a validator for date which user will be typing in textbox. for this wrote the code like

```
ko.validation.rules['date'] = {
    validator: function (value, validate) {
      //Custom logic
    },
    message: 'Please type proper date'
};

self.userDate = ko.observable(new Date()).extend({date: true });
```

This is working fine on tab out. But i need to call this validation on some delay(When the user stopped typing).

Any one could tell me how can i call this validation on delay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make sure the viewmodel is updated as the user is typing, use the `valueUpdate` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#parameters):

`<input data-bind="value: userDate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />`

You then throttle the observable:

```
self.userDate = ko.observable(new Date()).extend({
    throttle: 1000, //<- time in ms to wait before validation
    date: true
});
```

Throttle in this case waits 1000 ms after the last registered input event to perform the validation.

Comment: Thanks Anders... I was trying with afterKeyUp which was not firing at all.. This was the code that i need ..

Comment: Great! Knockout is a lovely framework. Once you get to know it, it almost feels like cheating. :)

Comment: Do not forget to inform your QA/Automation team, if you make this as its going to create failures as automation code hits elements faster than 100ms